# Flash Professional CS6 for Arabic Air Android project

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am working on an android application using Flash Professsional CS6 and the application contains Arabic content, my problem is when I transferred the application into the mobile, the Arabic letters appears separate and in the wrong order. Can I have your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this answer might be too late !

Use (tlf text) and make sure to embed the font .